# Where is the « Remove Doubles » function (UV) in Blender?

Tags: uv

I hope that the question title is self-explanatory. Thank you in advance for any help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As in 3D view: <kbd>M</kbd> ⇾ *By distance*